# Maxmind: does any of its geoip2 databases have county fips code?

Tags: geoip, maxmind

I would like to get county fips code from an IP address. Does anyone know whether Maxmind's geoip2 or legacy geoip database provide such information for an IP address? If not, which other companies provide geoip databases with county fips code. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GeoIP Legacy City databases have FIPS region codes for countries besides the US and Canada. The US and Canada regions use ISO 3166-2.

Although there isn't a one-to-one mapping, there are plenty of partial mappings between FIPS and ISO 3166-2 available that you can use. I know GeoNames provides one in their premium data dump.